# Relation between HandleBar js and Mustache js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

i'm very new to Handlebar js. In every article about the HandleBar js there is a word called (mustache js). So,
  1. What is the relation between Handllebar js and Mustache js?
  2. Is it necessary to read mustache js before handlebar js?
  3. What s advantage of HandleBar js over Mustache js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Handlebars.js is a superset of Mustache.js. It offers all the same ability to insert JSON into templates plus additional abilities to do some basic if/then, etc. In general, I find it much easier to do templating with Handlebars.

Mustache is very much about not having any logic in your template at all. Every piece that gets inserted into it should be pre-chewed so there's no need for any logic. I find that to not at all be realistic.

Just realized that I didn't answer one of your questions. No, it is not necessary to read about Mustache before using Handlebars. The Handlebars documentation is sufficient on its own.

P.S. One of our favorite Handlebars features is "helpers" which allow you to create new keywords in the language for specific things (for example, we use one to format numbers and sometimes replace them with "N/A" for zero values).

P.P.S. A great way to try out Handlebars and see some templates in action (and also to play with your own templates and JSON) is http://www.tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](http://sorescode.com/2010/09/12/benchmarks.html) website (which also provides a benchmark between the two)

> handlebars.js is a compiled mustache implementation with some additional
>   features